# Code for contract interaction works on Kovan but not on Ropsten

Tags: solidity, remix, ropsten, kovan

we deployed (via remix) the code below where one contract can influence a state variable in the other. For some reason if I deploy the contracts on Ropsten it doesn't work and if I deploy them on Kovan, this works just fine. Anyone any idea?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract A {

    uint public counter ; 
    function increment(uint add) {
       counter = counter + add;
    }
}

contract B {

    function delegateIncrement(uint add) {
        A("here the address for contract A").increment(add) ; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the error running out of gas, I even upped the gaslimit significantly, but that didn't work. Why is it running out of gas in Ropsten and not Kovan?

Comment: Since you mention that you are deploying via Remix: Any chance that you forgot to recompile B with the new address of A, as deployed on Ropsten? "Out of gas" is what you see in some interfaces for an invalid opcode, which seems more likely than a failure to send enough gas.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble *deploying* the contract, it's probably because Ropsten blocks are very full right now. Try using a gas price greater than 56 gwei.

Kovan is also running on Homestead, while Ropsten is on Byzantium. I don't know why that would make a difference though.

Comment: What do you mean by "blocks are very full?"

Comment: Deployingnis nog problem. It is the interaction that doesn't work in ropsten. If I use the function in contract A, the counter works fine. If I use the function in contract B, the counter doesn't chage value. I don't run into this problem on Kovan....